# TypeScript 2.0 and merging the react-router interface declared in Route.d.ts

Tags: typescript, react-router, typescript2.0

I want to add a name attribute to the RouteProps interface. Without it I get:

> error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & > IntrinsicClassAttributes> & RouteProp...'

If I add `name?: string;` to the external Route.d.ts file the error goes away.

I've tried to merge the modules a number of suggested ways without success.

The external Route.d.ts declaration starts out like this:

```
declare const self: self.Route;
type self = self.Route;
export default self;

declare namespace self {

    interface RouteProps extends React.Props<Route> {...
```

I'm using TypeScript 2.

Answer (score 0):

I hava the same question and I using "Module Augmentation": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

you can add a new file custom-route.d.ts and write code

```
declare module "react-router/lib/Route" {
    interface RouteProps {
        name?: String;
    }
}
```

you can see my question in
[Typescript custom @types package for @types/react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941806/typescript-custom-types-package-for-types-react-router/42943285#42943285)

Comment: Please, add some essential parts, from the link you have provided/ Link-only answers are not welcomed. :)