# Typescript custom @types package for @types/react-router

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-router, reactjs, typescript-typings

My project use react with typescript. I need to use react-breadcrumbs to show Breadcrumb for react-router.

Now I add two @type package to My package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
   "@types/react-breadcrumbs": "^1.3.7",
   "@types/react-router": "^3.0.8"
 }
```

react-breadcrumb need to use route.props.name to show name for breadcrumb, but when I use @type package in npm 
the Route.d.ts file has not name Props in the interface RouteProps.

```
interface RouteProps extends IndexRouteProps {
    path?: RoutePattern;
}
interface IndexRouteProps {
    component?: RouteComponent;
    components?: RouteComponents;
    getComponent?: (nextState: RouterState, callback: ComponentCallback) => void;
    getComponents?: (nextState: RouterState, callback: ComponentsCallback) => void;
    onEnter?: EnterHook;
    onChange?: ChangeHook;
    onLeave?: LeaveHook;
}
```

So I need to direct edit the Route.d.ts file in node_modules to

```
export interface RouteProps extends IndexRouteProps {
    path?: RoutePattern;
    name?: String;
}
```

If I no edit it I will compile error and show

> error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Readonly<...'

I think direct edit node_modules file is not good practice.

Can I custom the type file in other method?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the original typing. You can do that using "Module Augmentation": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

To test, add the following module declaration after import the original module:

```
declare module "react-router/lib/Route" {
    interface RouteProps {
        name?: String;
    }
}
```

like this:

```
import { RouteProps } from "@types/react-router";

declare module "react-router/lib/Route" {
    interface RouteProps {
        name?: String;
    }
}

let x: RouteProps;

x.name; // <- no error!
```

Now you can create a file to put your custom typings (e.g. custom-typings.d.ts) on your project and put that augmentation interface.

Comment: thanks, I create a file custom-route.d.ts and put the declare module code. It's compile success.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer: module augmentation. https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/03/typescript1-8-released

Short answer: file an issue or submit a PR at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Why is the second answer shorter? Because it will probably take you less time to do.

Best

Comment: thanks. I think module augmentation is better. Because, this problem is  type issue only for react-router and react-breadcrumbs.